# How to output results of a for loop to an asp label?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a for loop that captures LastWriteTime and the file name of the files within my word folder on my desktop. The loop works excellent when testing it to print to the console, but now I have the challenge of writing the results to an asp label. I'm new to this and could use some help.

C# Back-end code:
....

```
 namespace Name
 {
    class CaptureFileName
    {
        public string printNameFromWordFolder()
        {
            string[] wordFolder = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Word", "*.*");
            string TimeStamp;
            string FileName;

            for (int x = 0; x < wordFolder.Length; x++)
            {
                string timestamp = File.GetLastWriteTime(wordFolder[x]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wordFolder[x]).ToString();
                TimeStamp = timestamp;
                FileName = filename;
            }

            return TimeStamp + FileName;

        }
    }
    public partial class ClassName: System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            CaptureName print = new CaptureName();

            fileCount.Text = print.printNameFromWordFile();
        }
}
```

....

ASPX font-end code:
...

```
<td>
 <asp:Label ID="fileCount" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</td>
```

...

Comment: You could concatenate the pair timestamp+filename in every loop execution and return it to be shown in the label; personally, I would suggest a textarea as it allows you to use line breaks;

Comment: Tip: TimeStamp=timestamp overwrites the previous value, it doesn't add to it

Comment: Considering you never modify the result inside the loop so that the loop takes only the last element into account, I doubt it *works excellent when testing in the console*. It doesn't work there, as well.

Comment: Unless the output was written with a console.writeline inside the loop

Comment: @WiktorZychla Here's the console code:

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] wordFolder = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Desktop\Word", "*.*");

            for (int x = 0; x < wordFolder.Length; x++)
            {
                var timeStamp = File.GetLastWriteTime(wordFolder[x]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                Console.WriteLine(timeStamp + " " + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(wordFolder[x]));
            }

            Console.WriteLine(wordFolder.Count());

        }

Try it, I'm sure it'll work for you too :)

Comment: Try moving the Console.WriteLine outside the loop - then it will not work because of the same problem in your question